# SQL query generated by WP_Query is not the same what request echoes

Tags: get-posts

given this code:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat' => $cat,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'publish_from' => 1,
        'publish_to' => 1,
        's' => $s,
        'tag' => $tag,
        'paged' => (int)$next,
        'posts_per_page' => (int)$ppp
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    echo $query->request.'!<br>';
    $query = $query->get_posts();
    echo sizeof($query);die;
```

it echoes the following SQL:

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_16_posts.* FROM wp_16_posts WHERE 1=1
>   AND (wp_16_posts.publish_to IS NULL OR wp_16_posts.publish_to > now())
>   AND (wp_16_posts.publish_from IS NULL OR wp_16_posts.publish_from <
>   now()) AND (((wp_16_posts.post_title LIKE
>   '{77b35c99deebcd176e45c5740dc2f5707adf3f48c63f743d524469d6161873c4}rosszkor233{77b35c99deebcd176e45c5740dc2f5707adf3f48c63f743d524469d6161873c4}')
>   OR (wp_16_posts.post_excerpt LIKE
>   '{77b35c99deebcd176e45c5740dc2f5707adf3f48c63f743d524469d6161873c4}rosszkor233{77b35c99deebcd176e45c5740dc2f5707adf3f48c63f743d524469d6161873c4}')
>   OR (wp_16_posts.post_content LIKE
>   '{77b35c99deebcd176e45c5740dc2f5707adf3f48c63f743d524469d6161873c4}rosszkor233{77b35c99deebcd176e45c5740dc2f5707adf3f48c63f743d524469d6161873c4}')))
>   AND wp_16_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_16_posts.post_status =
>   'publish')) ORDER BY wp_16_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 8

running this in an SQL browser, it returns nothing. But above I echo the length of the result - its 8! So WP_Query cant run that SQL what I see... what can be wrong? Its the newest WordPress

Answer (score 1):

`$wp_query->result` is not the final stage of the query. It needs to be passed through `$wpdb` to be properly executed.

The main issue is the fact that the `LIKE` wildcards `%` have not been unescaped. If you replace the `{77b35c9 etc.}` sets of characters, including the brackets, with `%` you should get pretty much the final query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_16_posts.* FROM wp_16_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_16_posts.publish_to IS NULL OR wp_16_posts.publish_to > now()) AND (wp_16_posts.publish_from IS NULL OR wp_16_posts.publish_from < now()) AND (((wp_16_posts.post_title LIKE '%rosszkor233%') OR (wp_16_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%rosszkor233%') OR (wp_16_posts.post_content LIKE '%rosszkor233%'))) AND wp_16_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_16_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_16_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```

Comment: thats right, but it still returns nothing in SQL browser...

Comment: Then you probably don't have results. Is there a reason that you _expect_ results? Presumably you're not getting results, or you wouldn't be checking the SQL.

Comment: of course, the "rosszkor233" is a madeup word, doesnt exists. But the question is, why there are result hits in ->get_posts() ...